# Selenium, clicking buttons

Tags: python-2.7, selenium

I am having a hard time working out how to 'click' on this button using Seleniumn's ChromeDriver. I have attempted using the css_selector like so

```
submit_button = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.tm-control-group > btn-signin')
```

**Source**

```
<div class="tm-control-group">
<button class="tm-btn tm-btn-danger l10n login-info" type="button" rel="btn_signin" id="btn-signin">Log On</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `div.tm-control-group > btn-signin` would try to search `btn-signin` element, while you are looking for the `button` element instead. Either change the selector to:

```
div.tm-control-group > button
```

Or, even better, just locate the button by id:

```
button#btn-signin
```

Or, via:

```
driver.find_element_by_id("btn-signin")
```

Comment: Great thanks, could swear I tried this but apparently not :)

Answer (score 1):

> div.tm-control-group > btn-signin

This [`css_selector`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) would locate `<btn-signin>` element which has parent element as `<div class = 'tm-control-group'>` while you want to locate `<button>` element.

Actually `btn-signin` is value of `id` and `rel` attributes of the `<button>` element.

- To locate an element with `id` attribute value using [`css_selector`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) we use [`#id`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_id.asp). So correct [`css_locator`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) with `id` attribute value is :-

  ```
  div.tm-control-group > button#btn-signin
  ```
- To locate an element with other attribute value using [`css_selector`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) we use [`[attribute-name = 'attribute-value']`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attribute_value.asp). So correct [`css_locator`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) with `rel` attribute value is :-

  ```
  div.tm-control-group > button[rel = 'btn-signin']
  ```